# Add marging around png image TypeError:color must be int or single-element tuple

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a code that enables me to add margins around png images and it is working well, till I encountered a black and white color image. At this point, the code gives me an error like that
`TypeError: color must be int or single-element tuple`.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence

def add_margin(pil_img, top, right, bottom, left, color):
    width, height = pil_img.size
    new_width = width + right + left
    new_height = height + top + bottom
    result = Image.new(pil_img.mode, (new_width, new_height), color)
    result.paste(pil_img, (left, top))
    return result
    
im = Image.open('Sample.png')
for i, page in enumerate(ImageSequence.Iterator(im)):
    if i == 2: break
    page = add_margin(page, 150, 400, 400, 400, (255, 255, 255))
    page.save('Output.png')
```

Here's a sample image
[image]

I could solve it by changing this line in the function

```
result = Image.new(pil_img.mode, (new_width, new_height), 'white')
```

But I welcome any other ideas

Answer (score 2):

Since your image is in black and white mode, you should specify white as 1 instead of (255, 255, 255) because it is a binary value.